# Reputation for accepted duplicate close vote

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, reputation

To encourage people close duplicate questions, I think it should be rewarded with reputation.

For many repeating trivia questions, answering them is usually easier then searching for a good duplicate question/canonical answer. And on top of that, you get a reputation, when your duplicate answer is accepted/upvoted.

To make searching for duplicate question more attractive, the user that suggested duplicate should get some reputation, once/if the duplicate is accepted.

I believe that 10 rep is reasonable or even 15. After all, it's one time gain, comparing to potentially many upvotes a duplicate answer can receive.

Comment: Are you not afraid that by doing this, SO will become a "flagasdup race", and that no one will answer even relevant questions?

Comment: I think this is a bad idea as Mistalis has mentioned it will just encourage people to just close a question. What happens if the question gets re-opened, do they lose their rep? Or have they got another chance to gain more rep?

Comment: @Mistalis As I've suggested, the reputation would be gained only after the community agrees that the question is indeed duplicate.

Comment: @Albzi Would make sense to lose rep if the question is re-opened, just as you rep, when answer is un-accepted.

Comment: I would start with a badge maybe and when we consider rep, only 2 rep or so, similar to having a suggested edit approved.

Comment: Each badge, or action that provide rep comes with their bot. We already have so many. No one want to face the DupeBot. That tag you dupe of the 2nd Google Match of your exact title. They will turn low freq tag into Dupe graveyard. Where all question die as dupe.